# Application Switcher showing up on wrong monitor display

Tags: display, thunderbolt, application-switcher

I have an early 2015 MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra. I also have two Dell UltraSharp Infinity Edge monitors connected to it via two Thunderbolt Mini DisplayPort outputs.

In the System Preferences, I've arranged my two displays such that the menu bar is located in the monitor immediately in front of me.  The second monitor sits to my left.

The problem I'm having is that when I hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to activate the Application Switcher, the switcher always appears in the monitor on my left instead of the monitor in front of me.  I would think that the switcher would appear on the monitor whose display has the Menu bar.

Is there some way to configure my settings so that the switcher will always appear in the monitor in front of me, that is, the monitor that holds the Menu bar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The application switcher appears on the display where the Menu Bar is placed (the primary display).

However, if you have enabled **Automatically hide and show the Dock** in `System Preferences → Dock`, the app switcher will appear on the display which has **last shown** the Dock.

You can change the display which has last shown the Dock by moving the cursor to that display, move the cursor to the edge which houses the Dock and make the Dock appear momentarily.

This is the simplest approach to change the display on which application switcher needs to be shown in a multi monitor setup.

Comment: How interesting.  That's the answer!  I had my dock set to automatically hide so I guess I'll have to turn that off.  I wish Apple would make it so that we could automatically hide the dock AND set the monitor where I want the application switcher to always appear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are your displays arranged vertically? From my experience, arranging the menu bar on a display in the preferences will give that display priority horizontally, but the switcher will favor any display placed below another.

Answer (score 0):

My main monitor is set as my external display, yet Command + TAB is appearing on the other screen. Menu bar is on the main screen. It's moving the Dock that matters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/344571)